# If statement not working when using random numbers

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

My code has a turtle draw a dot at a random location. After it's drawn, another turtle goes forward to the same coordinates. What's supposed to happen is when the second turtle reaches the dot, the dot is supposed to disappear and instantly be redrawn somewhere else, but for some reason the `if` statement isn't working:

```
import turtle, random

t = turtle.Turtle()
t.speed(1)

dot = turtle.Turtle()
dot.hideturtle()
dot.speed(0)

dx = random.randint(1,100)
dy = random.randint(1,100)

tx = t.xcor()
ty = t.ycor()

def createDot(dx, dy):
  dot.penup()
  dot.goto(dx, dy)
  dot.pendown()
  dot.circle(5)

createDot(dx, dy)

t.goto(dx,dy)

if tx == dx and ty == dy:
  dot.clear()
  createDot(dx, dy)
```

Comment: What do you mean it isn't working? Are tx and dx, and ty and dy equal?

Comment: what is the error ?

Comment: you are getting the coordinates of the turtle (`t.xcor()`) before you make it go to the coordinates.

Comment: @Abderrahmen Mrabet the dot doesn't respawn in a different location

Comment: @Blorgbeard tx and dx should be equal, my issue is that the dot does not respawn in a different location when the turtle reaches the dot

Comment: See this lovely [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) blog for help.
If nothing else, you should be using basic `print` statements to trace your data values and program flow.

Answer (score 1):

Moving the turtle with

```
t.goto(dx,dy)
```

isn't changing the values of `tx` and `ty`. Try redoing

```
tx = t.xcor() 
ty = t.ycor()
```

before the if statement.

Comment: Easier still, just use `t.xcor()` and `t.ycor()` in your iff statement, and do away with `tx` and `ty` altogether.

Answer (score 0):

This is a fragile strategy to begin with:

```
if tx == dx and ty == dy:
```

as turtles wander a floating point plane and rarely land at the exact same spot.  Let's rework this code to actually take advantage of turtle's methods and eliminate `tx, ty` and `dx, dy` completely:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
from random import randint

def moveDot():
    dot.goto(randint(-100, 100), randint(-100, 100))

def chaseDot():
    if turtle.distance(dot) < 1:
        moveDot()
        turtle.setheading(turtle.towards(dot))

    turtle.forward(2)

    screen.ontimer(chaseDot, 50)

screen = Screen()

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.speed('slowest')

dot = Turtle('circle')
dot.shapesize(0.5)
dot.speed('fastest')
dot.penup()

chaseDot()

screen.exitonclick()
```

This has the turtle continuously chase the dot -- the dot relocates when the turtle reaches it.